# Differentiating a function composition

Tags: functional-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, vector-analysis

Given $g:R^n \rightarrow R^k$ and $h:R^k \rightarrow R$, we have $f(x) = h(g(x))$.

Using the chain rule, we can differentiate $f(x)$ to get

$f'(x) = \nabla^Th(g(x))g'(x)$

My question is why do we take the transpose of the gradient of $h$? Is it just to make sure the result is a scalar, since $f(x)$ is in $R$?

If so, does it mean that every time we do vector differentiation, we need to ensure the output matches the size of the result, and take transpose if necessary (i.e. no hard and fast rule of taking transpose)?

Comment: Edit your post and include the exact definitions of $'$ and $\nabla$.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. $'$ is derivative, $\nabla$ is gradient...

Comment: I asked this question because of Slide 18 in this set of slides. (https://see.stanford.edu/materials/lsocoee364a/03convexfunctions.pdf) In the proof for $f''(x)$, I had to find $f'(x)$ first and I was wondering why there was a need to take transpose for $\nabla h$. That's all the exact definitions of $h$ and $g$ that I know.

Comment: I'm asking row or column? Usually, if $h$ is a scalar function, $\nabla h(x)=(h′(x))^T$ with $\nabla h(x)$ column vector and $h′(x)$ row vector. But the **important** fact is that your result $f′(x)$ **can't** be a scalar if $n>1$.

Comment: In the slides the usual convention about rows and columns is inverted and the gradient is a row vector. In any case, if $n>1$, $f'(x)$ **can't be a scalar**.

Answer (score 0):

First, the result *isn't* an scalar, is a (row) vector. Second, lousy notation. The usual formula for the chain rule is
$$D(h\circ g)(x) = Dh(g(x))Dg(x)$$
where the product in the RHS is the matrix product. In your case $\nabla^T h(g(x))$ (i.e., $Dh(g(x))$) is a row vector. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant.

EDIT: example with $n = 3$, $k = 2$:
$$
\pmatrix{\partial_1 f&\partial_3 f&\partial_3 f} =
\pmatrix{\partial_1 h&\partial_2 h}
\pmatrix{\partial_1 g_1&\partial_2 g_1&\partial_3 g_1\cr\partial_1 g_2&\partial_2 g_2&\partial_3 g_2}.
$$

Comment: Ok, the result is a 1-by-1 vector. Actually, in my case, $g'(x)$ is a column vector, so the result is obtained by multiplying a row vector (after taking the transpose) and a column vector. My question still stands, do we take the transpose to get a 1x1 result?

Comment: @Rayne, **isn't** The result is a vector with $n$ components.

Comment: $g'(x)$ is a k-by-1 column vector. My lecturer mentioned the result is multiplying a row vector with a column vector.

Comment: @Rayne, are you sure that $g:R^n \rightarrow R^k$? $g'(x)$ *can't* be a vector if $n>1$.

Comment: @Rayne, see my edit. I've mixed the names of the functions in my original post,

Comment: Yes, $g:R^n \rightarrow R^k$.

Comment: @Rayne, if $f'(x) = $ row vector $\times$ column vector $=$ scalar, then $n = 1$.